# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function, already using group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Any idea why this error is happening in this query?

> 937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
>      *Cause:
>      *Action: Erro na linha: 1 Coluna: 8

```
select po.plop_sq_planej_oper,
               port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem, 
               (count(*)-1) as qnt_lista
          from sigiop.planejamento_operacional po,
               sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port,
               sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi,
               (select po1.plop_sq_planej_oper,
                       po1.plop_dt_criacao,
                       rtsi1.rtit_cd_rtitem
                  from sigiop.planejamento_operacional po1,
                       sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port1,
                       sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi1
                 where po1.plop_sq_planej_oper = port1.plop_sq_planej_oper
                   and port1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = rtsi1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
              group by po1.plop_sq_planej_oper,
                       po1.plop_dt_criacao,
                       rtsi1.rtit_cd_rtitem) port1
         where po.plop_sq_planej_oper = port.plop_sq_planej_oper
           and port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = rtsi.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
           and po.plop_dt_criacao >= port1.plop_dt_criacao(+)
           and rtsi.rtit_cd_rtitem = port1.rtit_cd_rtitem(+)
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` is on the inner `SELECT` (the one in the `FROM` statement), but your `COUNT` is in the outer `SELECT`, which is what the error is pointing out. Your inner `SELECT`  also does not use any aggregate functions, so the `GROUP BY` does not apply to it.

Comment: You are using `count(*)`, but there's no `GROUP BY` in the main query,

Comment: Also, please use current join syntax instead of joins form 1989.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your query as below -

```
SELECT po.plop_sq_planej_oper,
       port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem, 
       (count(*)-1) as qnt_lista
  FROM sigiop.planejamento_operacional po
  JOIN sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port ON po.plop_sq_planej_oper = port.plop_sq_planej_oper
  JOIN sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi ON port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = rtsi.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT po1.plop_sq_planej_oper,
                    po1.plop_dt_criacao,
                    rtsi1.rtit_cd_rtitem
               FROM sigiop.planejamento_operacional po1
               JOIN sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port1 ON po1.plop_sq_planej_oper = port1.plop_sq_planej_oper
               JOIN sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi1 ON port1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = rtsi1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
              GROUP BY po1.plop_sq_planej_oper,
                       po1.plop_dt_criacao,
                       rtsi1.rtit_cd_rtitem) port1 ON po.plop_dt_criacao >= port1.plop_dt_criacao
                                                   AND rtsi.rtit_cd_rtitem = port1.rtit_cd_rtitem
 GROUP BY po.plop_sq_planej_oper,
          port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem;
```

Comment: There is still a problem with the outer SELECT list including aggregated and non-aggregated items, and the  non-aggregated items are not included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I did't notice that. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the query starts with

```
select po.plop_sq_planej_oper,
       port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem, 
       (count(*)-1) as qnt_lista
```

but ends without

```
group by po.plop_sq_planej_oper, port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
```

I would also recommend writing it using standard ANSI joins, as

```
select po.plop_sq_planej_oper
     , port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
     , count(*) - 1 as qnt_lista
from   sigiop.planejamento_operacional po
       join sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port
            on  port.plop_sq_planej_oper = po.plop_sq_planej_oper
       join sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi
            on  rtsi.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
       left join
            ( select distinct
                     po1.plop_sq_planej_oper
                   , po1.plop_dt_criacao
                   , rtsi1.rtit_cd_rtitem
              from   sigiop.planejamento_operacional    po1
                     join sigiop.planejamento_operacional_rt port1
                          on  port1.plop_sq_planej_oper = po1.plop_sq_planej_oper
                     join sigiop.rt_subitem rtsi1
                          on  rtsi1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem = port1.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem
            ) port1
            on  port1.plop_dt_criacao <= po.plop_dt_criacao
            and port1.rtit_cd_rtitem = rtsi.rtit_cd_rtitem
group by
       po.plop_sq_planej_oper
     , port.rtsi_cd_rtsubitem;
```